# How to upload a large file to remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, file-transfer

I have a 30 GB SQL file (Oracle db) on my local machine. I want to upload it to a remote machine and import it to Oracle. What it the quickest and most efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say FTP. I use Mozilla for this. There is also SSH or SCP. Both ways requires proper credentials which are easily referenced in a search engine.

Comment: What OSes? I'd go with rsync or resilio sync, but it really depends on what the remote machines are.

Comment: It depends. E.g. if your upload speed is slow enough then the quickest and most efficient way may be to send a homing pigeon with micro SD card with your file on it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is a Windows machine hosted on Azure

Answer (score 1):

1) due to speed problems, I always upload large file on my [**GDrive**](http://drive.google.com) ([**files.fm**](http://files.fm) or etc), and then just copy shareable url and download on Target PC.

That's much faster with my experience.

2) To go further, you can create a folder(&make it shareable) in your GDrive, and bookmark its url in your browsers (or remember it with URL-shorteners, like:  bit.ly/james_gordon_files).